# How to know which Tiles build a rendered Image obtained by a Map Query?

Tags: tiles, mapbox, rendering

as Test Purpose for my app, I want to know exactly, which Tiles were used to render the result image I get by query.

I.e. I want to see a bounding box of 500px*300px with zoom 13 of Location `48.42,12.93` and I query that in `api.mapbox.com` like this `http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-zr0njcqy/12.93,48.42,13/500x300.png`, then I would get the next image
[image]

Then I would like to know how I can know the specific tiles*, which were used to render this image 500x300.